# How to dynamically change the position of a label according to the string length of another label?

Tags: iphone

I had two labels label1 and label2 and a tableview ,when the user click the tableview the content of the tableview is displayed in two labels.means if the tableview cell contain stack  and 1 ,1 in the text-label.text. i need to display stack in the label1 and 1 in the label2 ,i have done this .but the problem is when the tableview cell content is big i.e.,instead of stack there is stackoverflow it was overlapped with label2 due to big string content
For example stack:1 is ok but when the content is stackoverflow it will appears stackoverflow1
or stackove...1 something like that.so My need is label2 must change its position according to the string length of label1.How to do this?.i hope u understand my question.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get string size with the help of following code

```
CGSize stringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];
```

Now you can get frame of the first label and then its text size as well. I hope now it will be easy for you to adjust the postion of second label. In case of any problem let me know. 
Here is my code for getting number of lines of a label so that I can get the first label's height to add the second label after it.

```
CGSize stringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];
    int labelwidth = firstLabel.width;
    int number_of_lines = stringSize.width/labelwidth;
    int size = stringSize.width;
    int reminder = size % labelwidth;
    if(reminder != 0){
        number_of_lines++;
    }
// now first label height will be

rowHeight = number_of_lines*FONT_SIZE + GAP_BETWEEN_ROWS
```

Now you can use this rowHeigh as frame.origin.y of your second label.

Best of luck

Comment: where did i put the above cde?in viewdidload?

Comment: ,i am getting error that width is not set in property ,FONT_SIZE undeclared

Comment: you will put this code where you are adding those labels. Actually the rowHeight will serve as y position of your second label. So put this code before adding your second label.

Comment: place any integer value like 12, 14 or whatever as font size. I used a constant FONT_SIZE which you did not do. Thats why you are getting an error. Replace FONT_SIZE with the font size you are using in your first label.

Comment: @Aqueel i put the the two labels in uinterfacebuilder

Comment: then make IBOutlets of both labels and use those IBOutlets to make changes in labels or changing their frames.

Answer (score 1):

you can set any frame you your label when you setting new text to it:

```
[yourLabel setFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
```

just calculate it according length of new text. 
But... do you REALLY need 2 labels? If thay placed in one line and you do so only becouse of you have 2 words, you may do this much easer:
Use 1 label with widgh of all screen and set new text like this:

```
[yourLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat(@"%@ %@", text1, text2)]];
```

Comment: then, try to do as I sed in the begining. Aqueel posted how you can calculate requaered length

Comment: you are absolutely correct,[YourLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat(@"%@ %@", text1, text2)]];this is exactly what i want to do,but i am getting null value for lable2 in the first tap of the uitableviewcell.thats why i changed the way by putting tw labels.

Comment: Sorry, I cand understand what are you trying to say: what is `lable2`?

Comment: i need to change the position of the lble2 ,according to the sting length of label1.

Comment: oh... let me explane: in my code, 'YourLabel' - is just one `UILabel`. `text1` and `text2` - is two `NSString`s This code puts 2 strings into one label. If you need 2 labels, put 1st string to 1st label, 2nd string to 2nd label, calculate length of texts of this label just like Aqueel sed, set new frame to first label, then, move your 2nd label  to new coordinates, according 1st label's widgh (`label1.frame.size.widgth`)

Comment: Please do not start variable and method names with uppercase characters. Per convention they should start with lowercase characters, uppercase is for types (class names, enums, structs), defines and sometimes constants.

Comment: what error exacely? may by you calculate it wrong? try to `NSLog()` it BEFORE setting

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this if you want show on two separate labels you have to calculate the width of first label according to you text set the frame of first label and then add say 5px to the width of first label this will become x position of your next label.